# How can I delete a file with assembly (x86) on Windows?

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2012, x86, irvine32

I created a program that can create files and update them, but now I want to delete them, but I haven't found a solution.

I am using the Irvine Library and there I found a method to create files, but there is no method to delete them.

I have heard about using int 80h and int 41h, but nothing works.

Comment: `Int 80h` would be for Linux and BSD platforms and I am guessing that when you say Int 41h you mean Int 21h/AH=42h which is an MS-DOS interrupt. Neither of those methods can be used when creating 32-bit Windows programs with Irvine32. You could invoke the `DeleteFile` WIn32 API method in kernel32.dll

Answer (score 1):

Irvine32 is a library designed to make it easier to write Windows applications using MASM. If there is no built-in function to delete a file, you will need to call the function provided by the Windows API, [`DeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx). The code might look like this:

```
push   DWORD PTR [pszFileName]   ; push a pointer to the name of the file to be deleted
call   DeleteFile                ; returns 0 on failure; non-zero on success
```

where `pszFileName` is a pointer to an array of WORD-sized characters, terminated by a NUL (0) character, which will be treated as a string containing the name of the file to be deleted.

Because the `DeleteFile` function is exported by Kernel32, you will need to link to `kernel32.lib` using `INCLUDELIB` or a linker option. Also, if you have a `windows.inc` include file, then you should include that to give you access to the function's prototype. Otherwise, you can define it yourself:

```
EXTRN _DeleteFileW@4:PROC
```

(assuming a 32-bit target; on 64-bit, it would be `_DeleteFile@8`, since pointers are 8 bytes in size).